# What this Query does?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-delete

I am not sure in human language what this query will eventually do in SQL Server.

The idea is that if an order with the amount X exist in both tables #Temp and #TempDuplPos it should be deleted from the table #Temp.

```
DELETE #Temp
FROM #Temp
INNER JOIN #TempDuplPos ON (#Temp.[OrderNumber] = #TempDuplPos.[OrderNumber])
AND (#Temp.[Amount] = #TempDuplPos.[Amount])
```

What I did to test is the following:

```
SELECT 1 AS OrderNumber, 10 AS Amount
INTO #Temp

SELECT 1 AS OrderNumber, 10 AS Amount
INTO #TempDuplPos

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES (2,20)

INSERT INTO #TempDuplPos
VALUES (3,30)

DELETE #Temp
FROM #Temp
INNER JOIN #TempDuplPosON (#Temp.[OrderNumber] = #TempDuplPos.[OrderNumber])
AND (#Temp.[Amount] = #TempDuplPos.[Amount])

SELECT *
FROM #Temp

SELECT *
FROM #TempDuplPos

DROP TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #TempDuplPos
```

It looks like it does the job but I am not sure I miss something which will hit me in a large data set. So my question is, is this query doing what I want? If no what it does? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: This delete from the table where the Columns matches with other column the other Table.

Comment: Yes @joakim-danielson I tested it of course in a small dataset.

Comment: This question is garbled--"the idea" jumps around among the code & what it does & what you want some code to do. When you make it clear, it will be asking two questions. Please ask just one. Anyway probably you don't care about one of them. PS Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It deletes records from `#Temp` table where records on `#TempDuplPos` with the same `OrderNumber` and `Amount` exists.

If you want to only delete records with a specific amount you need to add a `where` clause:

```
DELETE #Temp
FROM #Temp
INNER JOIN #TempDuplPos 
    ON (#Temp.[OrderNumber] = #TempDuplPos.[OrderNumber])
    AND (#Temp.[Amount] = #TempDuplPos.[Amount])
WHERE #Temp.[Amount] = @Amount
```